# Woocommerce thank you page ajax working on desktop but not mobile

Tags: php, ajax, mobile, woocommerce

I really try not to come here often but I'm at a complete loss.  I've made some custom code on my woocommerce checkout page so a user will get their order to download in email form along with their standard invoice.  For the life of me I cannot understand why it works perfect on desktop but javascirpt/jQuery just completly does not work on mobile.  The code is the same for both?  I included the whole file but it's the ajax calls with the url going to emailDownloadFdd.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<?php
session_start();
include_once("hidden");
$databaseClass = new databaseClass();
$conn = $databaseClass->connect();
/**
 * Thankyou page
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/thankyou.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     3.2.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}
?>

<div class="woocommerce-order">

    <?php if ( $order ) : ?>

        <?php if ( $order->has_status( 'failed' ) ) : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed"><?php _e( 'Unfortunately your order cannot be processed as the originating bank/merchant has declined your transaction. Please attempt your purchase again.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--error woocommerce-thankyou-order-failed-actions">
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'Pay', 'woocommerce' ) ?></a>
                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_page_permalink( 'myaccount' ) ); ?>" class="button pay"><?php _e( 'My account', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </p>

        <?php else : ?>

            <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>
            <?php
            if(isset($_SESSION['randomid']))
            {  $randomID = $_SESSION['randomid'];
                $billingEmail = wp_kses_post( $order->get_billing_email() );
                $method = wp_kses_post( $order->get_payment_method_title() );
                $databaseClass->fdd_sales($randomID, $method);
                //$databaseClass->emailAndRandIdForDownloadLinks($_SESSION['randomid'], $billingEmail);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO fddDownloadInfo (email, time, randomid)
                VALUES ('$billingEmail', NOW(), $randomID)";

                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    $istrue = 1;
                } else {
                    $istrue = 0;
                }

                //new code 9-13

                $sqlGetEmail = "select email from fddDownloadInfo where randomid = $randomID and time > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY";
                $resultEmail = $conn->query($sqlGetEmail);
                if($resultEmail->num_rows > 0)
                {
                    while($rowEmail = $resultEmail->fetch_assoc())
                    {
                        $phpEmail = $rowEmail['email'];
                    }
                }

                if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Safari') && !strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome')) {
                    $browserSafari = 'Safari';
                }
                if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
                    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                }
                if (strlen(strstr($agent, 'Firefox')) > 0) {
                    $browserFirefox = 'firefox';
                }
                if($browserSafari == 'Safari' || $browserFirefox == 'firefox')
                {
                    $browser = "safariOrFirefox";
                }  

                if($browser != "safariOrFirefox")
                {
                ?>
                <script>

                    var myJSON = <?php echo $randomID; ?>;
                    var email = "<?php echo $phpEmail; ?>";
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                   $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "https://hidden/SendGrid-Starter-Kit-master/SendGrid-API/emailDownloadFdd.php",
                                    //data: "array=" + myJSON,
                                    data: {array: myJSON, email: email},

                        });
                    });
                        </script>

                <?php
                }
                else
                {
                ?>
                <script>

                    var myJSON = <?php echo $randomID; ?>;
                    var email = "<?php echo $phpEmail; ?>";
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                    $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    async: false,
                                    url: "https://hidden/SendGrid-Starter-Kit-master/SendGrid-API/emailDownloadFdd.php",
                                    //data: "array=" + myJSON,
                                    data: {array: myJSON, email: email},

                        });
                    });


                </script>
                 <?php
                }

                ?>


                <?php
                //end 9-13 code

                echo "<a style='border 1px solid black; padding 15px; color: white; background-color: blue; border-radius: 5px;' href='https://hidden/payment-received/'>Download your FDDs Here</a><div><br>";

            }
            else {
                echo "";
            }
            //rf_funds insert calls
            if(isset($_SESSION['rf250']))
            {
                header("Location: https://hidden/franchise_dashboard/model/insertNewFunds.php");
                //echo $_SESSION['rf250'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
                if(isset($_SESSION['rf500']))
            {
                header("Location: https://hidden/franchise_dashboard/model/insertNewFunds.php");
                //echo $_SESSION['rf250'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
                if(isset($_SESSION['rf1000']))
            {
                header("Location: https://hidden/franchise_dashboard/model/insertNewFunds.php");
                //echo $_SESSION['rf250'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
            //pv calls
                if(isset($_SESSION['pv250']))
            {
                header("Location: https://hidden/franchise_dashboard/model/insertNewFunds.php");
                //echo $_SESSION['rf250'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
                if(isset($_SESSION['pv500']))
            {
                header("Location: https://hidden/franchise_dashboard/model/insertNewFunds.php");
                //echo $_SESSION['rf250'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
                if(isset($_SESSION['pv1000']))
            {
                header("Location: https://hidden/franchise_dashboard/model/insertNewFunds.php");
                //echo $_SESSION['rf250'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
            //ad funds calls
            if(isset($_SESSION['ad250']))
            {
                header("Location: https://hidden/franchise_dashboard/model/insertNewFunds.php");
                //echo $_SESSION['rf250'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
                if(isset($_SESSION['ad500']))
            {
                header("Location: https://hidden/franchise_dashboard/model/insertNewFunds.php");
                //echo $_SESSION['rf250'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }
                if(isset($_SESSION['ad1000']))
            {
                header("Location: https://hidden/franchise_dashboard/model/insertNewFunds.php");
                //echo $_SESSION['rf250'];
            }
            else
            {
                echo "";
            }

            ?>

            <ul class="woocommerce-order-overview woocommerce-thankyou-order-details order_details">

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__order order">
                    <?php _e( 'Order number:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_order_number(); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__date date">
                    <?php _e( 'Date:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php if ( is_user_logged_in() && $order->get_user_id() === get_current_user_id() && $order->get_billing_email() ) : ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__email email">
                        <?php _e( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php echo $order->get_billing_email(); ?></strong>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__total total">
                    <?php _e( 'Total:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                    <strong><?php echo $order->get_formatted_order_total(); ?></strong>
                </li>

                <?php if ( $order->get_payment_method_title() ) : ?>
                    <li class="woocommerce-order-overview__payment-method method">
                        <?php _e( 'Payment method:', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
                        <strong><?php echo wp_kses_post( $order->get_payment_method_title() ); ?></strong>
                    </li>
                <?php endif; ?>

            </ul>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou_' . $order->get_payment_method(), $order->get_id() ); ?>
        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', $order->get_id() ); ?>

    <?php else : ?>

        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received.', 'woocommerce' ), null ); ?></p>

    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Comment: *I really try not to come here often but I'm at a complete loss.*  You don't have to be at a complete loss to visit!  This is a great place for resources and basic information as well!  --  When you say it doesn't work on mobile --  Is that multiple devices, different browsers?  IE Android/iOS/Safari/Chrome/Firefox etc etc

Comment: haha cool. I just remember people being pretty rude to me before.  But then again back then I was a real noob.  Yea it's any browser, safari, firefox, chorme.  Just completely does not work on mobile?

Comment: Are you using a mobile console/debug?  Are there any errors in the console/network tabs?

Comment: I did try a mobile console a couple of days ago but nothing really showed up.  Did not do network tab but I could look into that.  Our theme is not responsive meaning it breaks up mobile and desktop(it's newspapper 9).  Not sure if this has anything to do with it?

Comment: Maybe it's something on the wordpress page itself?